# Matrix Similarity of non-diagonalizeable Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

In one of the problems for past entrance exams to X university, I don't know how to proceed with this question.

Let a,b,c,d,e,f be complex numbers and,  $ A=\left[
\matrix
{
2&a&b&c \\
0&2&d&e \\
0&0&2&f \\
0&0&0&3   
}
\right] $
and, 
$ B=\left[
\matrix
{
2&1&0&0 \\
0&2&-1&0 \\
0&0&2&1 \\
0&0&0&3   
}
\right] $

I have to find out for which values of a,b,c,d,e and f, are A and B similar matrices.

So I got $B$ into Jordan Canonical Form, since it cannot be diagonalized, where I got $ J=\left[
\matrix
{
2&1&0&0 \\
0&2&1&0 \\
0&0&2&0 \\
0&0&0&3   
}
\right] $
But I don't know where to proceed from there. I know A and B are similar if their Jordan forms are similar, or their rational canonical form, in case the Jordan Form doesn't exist. But I don't know how to abstractly get the other matrix into something like Jordan Form.

Any help would be appreciated, especially more literature on this subject. In class I only covered up to Jordan Form, regarding matrix similarity, so this might be a different type of question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: the Jordan form of $B$ tells you that the nullity of $A-2I$ must be $1$. (You can see this from $B$ directly, in fact; no need for the Jordan form.)

Comment: @symplectomorphic Since the nullity of $B-2I$ is 1, the nullity of $A-2I$ must also be 1. Then, this all ammounts to saying that $detA_2=\left[
\matrix
{
a&b \\
0&d 
}
\right]\neq0 $?
Or am I making a logic jump somewhere?